# Manipulate Wordpress generated content before it is displayed

Tags: wordpress

I'm a Wordpress virgin, thrown into something I don't know much about, just trying to help.  I do know a few things about php.

I would like to know if somehow in wordpress (not via an update vulnerable hack) it is possible to see and manipulate the full page content, before it is displayed ?

I would like to check a few things in the page meta-data tags, cross reference that with data in the body on various places, make a few changes here and there if needed and THEN hand it over to Wordpress again.

Some sort of callback, at the last moment, with the full page's content in a php variable.

Maybe this is simply not possible ?
Hope to learn something.  Cheers.

Comment: I would look into creating a plugin specific to your site so that it will filter whatever you are trying to cross reference.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: I ended up 'fixing' the issue a completely different way.  So this is not that urgent anymore.  For completeness however I want to add that I tried adding a filter to the template file: add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' ); and that worked except that content did not contain the header meta data.  So there must be a better filter than 'the_content' (maybe?) that gives me the full content ?

Comment: This might help you https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-apply-a-filter-to-the-entire-page

Comment: Thanks. Interesting !  That should do the trick indeed.  I'll test it when I can.